# Can you control how vertex-shader outputs are interpolated over a polygon?

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader, direct3d, cg

It's a common problem that outputs from a vertex shader are linearly interpolated as 3D/4D vector values, which leads to artifacts. For instance if a vertex shader outputs a normalised vector, you still typically need to renormalise it in your fragment shader.

Do D3D/OpenGL/Cg provide any way to control *how* interpolation is performed? e.g. can you suggest what the interpolated values *mean* so that some context-aware interpolation could be performed?

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers for glsl

Comment: Thanks. Looks like for the purposes of this question, the answer is "yes, but not in the way you want"

Comment: Perhaps you could share what kind of interpolation you'd ideally want to do? Are you actually looking for ways to slerp your normals, or was that just an example?

Comment: @Paul-Jan I guess normals is the only concrete example, but I suppose I was wondering if you could do something like actually write a shader to do the interpolation. Since a pixel shader can't see the vertices involved, this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [GLSL interpolation qualifiers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Interpolation_qualifiers) mentioned by Pavel Beliy, Direct3D (HLSL) has a limited set of `Interpolation Modifiers` that you can set on each member of data structs or on any arguments that are passed to the pixel shader. See the remarks section of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The set of supported modifiers is limited to **linear, centroid, nointerpolation, noperspective and sample** (see link for details).

Unfortunately, the wording of your question and comment seems to suggest you have a need for more detailed control over the interpolation technique used. For example, none of the will solve the need for renormalizing interpolated vectors.

Comment: Yeah, these are all very specialised 'tweaks' rather than being able to inject any sort of intelligence into the interpolation.